# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and Failed to fetch (nodejs, graphql, apollo)

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am newbie on JS frameworks, so sorry if my question is easy but I didn't find any solution on my Google friend :)

I am creating a web app with ReactJS in Front-End, NodeJS in Back-End, GraphQL and Apollo.

I have my Back-End that works on `localhost:4001/api` (I am viewing the GraphQL interface with a query).

I have my Front-End that's working when I am not connected to my server. But when I am connected it, I have two errors (I think they are linked).

I have in my console :
[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpIcc.png)

I resolved the cors error but here, I am blocked. I tried bearer-authentication, but I'm not sure how can I use it and I'm not sure it's the a problem, but bearer solved this two bugs, but created the bug "Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400" (is it permission?)

You can view my github repo here : https://github.com/tiffanyLestroubac/ReactJs-NodeJs-GraphQl-App

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Finally, it's my query was wrong :))